# python How sort list in one line and return it

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list and I want to sort this list and return it from the function in one line.

I tried the return of `list1.sort()` but the output is None and not the `list1` sorted.

Is there a way to sort the list and return in one line?

Comment: There's a builtin function for that ... `sorted` ...

Comment: Why is this being voted to close for not demonstrating a minimal understanding? The question stated the code used, the actual return value, and the expected return value, and stated a clear question. It's evident that there's at least a minimal understanding of the problem here.

Comment: Why the requirement that it be one line? Granted, that require is easily satisfied in this case, but still ... are you playing code golf?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, but there is a subtle difference between sorting a list and returning a sorted _version_ of the list

Answer (score 9):

Use sorted.

```
>>>x = ["c","b","1"]
>>>sorted(x)
["1","b","c"]
```

`x.sort()` should return `None`, since that is how method `sort` works. Using `x.sort()` will sort x, but it doesn't return anything.

For more ways to sort look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: If you want to improve your answer, you could point out to OP *why* `list1.sort()` should return `None` by normal python conventions.

Answer (score 2):

usually you would say

```
sorted(list1)              # returns a new list that is a sorted version of list1
```

But sometimes you the sort to be in-place because other things are referencing that list

`list1.sort()` returns None, so your options are

```
list1[:] = sorted(list1)    # still makes a temporary list though
```

or

```
sorted(list1) or list1      # always ends up evaluating to list1 since None is Falsey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [6, 7, 4, 23, 10, 79]
list2 = [list1.pop(list1.index(min(list1))) for i in range(len(list1))]
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 7, 10, 23, 79]
```